# Islamic words and meanings

Tags: support

Excuse me, I know that meta is about using this site and my question is only indirectly about using this site.

There are a lot of words like Riba and others that an average westerner never has heard of, and even if so, lacks the proper Islamic understanding.

Is there a site (aside of wikipedia) where I can look up these terms? Maybe not only lookup on the fly but read through them?

They are mostly (or all?) Arabic, just as most terms in Christianity are Greek or Latin in origin. How can I improve understanding of Arabic language?

Comment: If such a resource doesn't already exist, or even if it does, this would probably be an excellent idea for a community wiki post.

Comment: Hm... all Islamic terms should be in Arabic or have their origins in this language since the Qur'an was revealed in Arabic and Muhammad was an Arab. However, due to historical circumstances and regional effects, we may say some none Arabic terms exist, but as far as I know only in mostly Asian non-Arabic communities: like "namaz" referring to prayer which is common in Turkish, Persian and Urdu if I'm not mistaken, also I've read the term "pak" which may refer to the Arabic "tahir" (~ritually clean) in places where I suppose Urdu is used.